# Is there a way to show two SQL queries at once in Azure Studio?

Tags: sql

I need to see one SQL statement result while composing another statement, but it isn't obvious that it is possible

Comment: Open a second connection/window? Copy the results into Excel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have been using Azure Studio for 3 weeks and I finally had a need to see results of a SQL query and to compose another query on another panel.  It wasn't obvious how to do it initially, so I figured a SQL expert would assist

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Data Studio: View > Editor Layout > Split Left